# Best way to transpose or pivot an array of categorical variables for Spark ML encoding

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on setting up categorical variables for spark ML models.  Instead of a column with individual categorical variables, I have a column with an array of categorical variables.  See example data below.

(Even though these are numbers, they represent a category).

I need to isolate these into individual features, for example, it's important to preserve that #1, #3, #6 and #7 have category 19, regardless of what other categories are in the array.

I could use SQL to manually identify all of the categorical variables and create a column for each.  But that doesn't seem elegant, I think there must be a better way to get all of the categories pivoted to columns and then designated a 1 or 0, which could then be one-hot encoded.  Or, I'm wondering if there's a better way in general to think about the problem.

I'm using scala 2.2.0 (and can't upgrade at the moment) so I can't use the newer array functions.

```
+---------------+----------------+
|id             |categorical_code|
+---------------+----------------+
|1              |           [19] |
|2              |       [87, 19] |
|3              |           [18] |
|4              |           [96] |
|5              |           [18] |
|6              |  [111, 22, 19] |
|7              |  [161, 19, 18] |
|8              |           [12] |
|9              |          [170] |
+---------------+----------------+
```

Output needed (I think) something like:

```
id,cat_12,cat_18,cat_19,cat_22,cat_87,cat_111,cat_161,cat_170
1,,,1,,,,,
2,,,1,,1,,,
3,,1,,,,,,
4,,,,,,,,
5,,1,,,,,,
6,,,1,1,,1,1,
7,,1,1,,,,,
8,1,,,,,,,1
9,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 2):

We can explode out the array into separate rows, then use a groupby-pivot to obtain the required output.

```
val df2 =
  df.
    select(
      df("id"),
      explode(df("categorical_code")).as("categorical_code"),
      lit(1).as("categorical_code_exist")
    )

df2.show()
+---+----------------+----------------------+
| id|categorical_code|categorical_code_exist|
+---+----------------+----------------------+
|  1|              19|                     1|
|  2|              87|                     1|
|  2|              19|                     1|
|  3|              18|                     1|
|  4|              96|                     1|
|  5|              18|                     1|
|  6|             111|                     1|
|  6|              22|                     1|
|  6|              19|                     1|
|  7|             161|                     1|
|  7|              19|                     1|
|  7|              18|                     1|
|  8|              12|                     1|
|  9|             170|                     1|
+---+----------------+----------------------+

val df3 =
  df2.
    groupBy("id").
    pivot("categorical_code").
    agg(coalesce(first(df2("categorical_code_exist")))).
    orderBy("id")

df3.show()
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| id|  12|  18|  19|  22|  87|  96| 111| 161| 170|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1|null|null|   1|null|null|null|null|null|null|
|  2|null|null|   1|null|   1|null|null|null|null|
|  3|null|   1|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|
|  4|null|null|null|null|null|   1|null|null|null|
|  5|null|   1|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|
|  6|null|null|   1|   1|null|null|   1|null|null|
|  7|null|   1|   1|null|null|null|null|   1|null|
|  8|   1|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|
|  9|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|   1|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+

df3.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 12: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 18: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 19: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 22: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 87: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 96: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 111: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 161: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 170: integer (nullable = true)
```